# Let $V=\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})$ prove $\varphi_j(p)=p(j)$ is a basis of $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})'$

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I would appreciate help with the first part of a problem I am self-studying:

> > Let $V=\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})$ prove $\varphi_j(p)=p(j)$ is a [dual] basis of $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})'$

I think I should first show the $\varphi_j(p)$ are linear independent:

If $a_0\varphi_0+a_1\varphi_1+a_2\varphi_2=0$ then all the $a_i$ are $0$.

Taking $(a_0\varphi_0+a_1\varphi_1+a_2\varphi_2)p(j)=0$ I would like to show each $a_j=0$ but I don't see how to do that.

Maybe my whole approach is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain your notation a little more?  I don't know what $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is or what $p(j)$ is.  Do you mean that $V$ is the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most 2?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Yes. Sorry for not being adequately explicit. And $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})'$ is the dual space. I am assuming $p(j)$ is $p$ evaluated at $j$. That is part of my problem as that would be a scalar.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese And at this point, it is not know what the basis of $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is. In fact, that is the second part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show linear independence, we need to show that if $a_0\phi_0 + a_1\phi_1 + a_2\phi_2  = 0$, then $a_i = 0$ for $i=0,1, 2$.  We know that $\Phi =a_0\phi_0 + a_1\phi_1 + a_2\phi_2 $ is an element of $V^{'}$, the dual space of $V$, and so $\Phi$ is a map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  We are assuming that $\Phi = 0$, or in other words, $\Phi(p) = 0$ for every $p\in V$.

Consider $p = (x-1)(x-2) = x^2 -3x + 2 \in V$.  By our previous assumption we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& \Phi(p) \\ 
&=& (a_0\phi_0 + a_1\phi_1 + a_2\phi_2)(p) \\
&=& a_0\phi_0(p) + a_1\phi_1(p) + a_2\phi_2(p) \\
&=& a_0p(0) + a_1p(1) + a_2p(2)\\
&=& a_0(2) + a_1(0) + a_2(0)\\
&=& 2a_0
\end{eqnarray}

This implies that $a_0 = 0$.  So now we can play this same game (i.e., find other polynomials $q, r$) to show that $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 0$.  This would prove the linear independence of $\phi_0, \phi_1$, and $\phi_2$.

Comment: Nice. It looks as if this also answers the second part - to find the corresponding basis $(p_0, p_1, p_2)$ of $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb{R})$ if you scale appropriately. Then, for for your example, $\varphi_0(p(0))$ would $=1$ in accordance with the definition of a dual basis.

Comment: With pleasure. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised this question entailed such a creative approach. Usually the problems to a large extent involve correctly applying definitions and using an example as a template. But I am a self-studier with no math background and haven't been to class for about 50 years. So maybe this was intimated in a lecture. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew Glad to help.  Sometimes there are clever tricks/techniques that you learn along the way that would be hard to come up with yourself.  Best of luck in your studies!